# Destructor for kfp pipelines

Tags: kubeflow-pipelines

I'm working on kubeflow(kf) pipelines that calls other kf pipelines.

We use a top level parent pipeline, to call out multiple child pipelines in parallel. During development and testing it is often the case where we would like to kill a complete run (all parent and child pipelines). Is there a destructor like mechanism in kf pipelines to terminate such "child" pipelines when a parent is terminated.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your pipeline launcher components so that they catch the Kubernetes' shutdown signal and terminate the pipeline they've started.

You can also try using Exit handler (although it cannot access any in-pipeline data).